# Login failed for user 'sc' even after creating user

Tags: iis, sql-server, connection, sql-server-2016

I am trying to run a web application but I just cannot login with a user account (**sc**). I keep getting

> Login failed for user 'sc'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'sc'.

---

I have given the user **sc** the following permissions

[image]

The login Status is **enabled** and permission to connect is also **granted**

---

My connection string -

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="43200" maxRequestLength="104856"   />

  </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" />-->
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;UID=sc;PWD=mystrongpassword;initial catalog=test;"/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is my Event log -

```
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/19/2016 3:12:31 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/19/2016 9:42:31 AM 
Event ID: 5512cef4f9054c2093a8899c987115be 
Event sequence: 7 
Event occurrence: 3 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Dashboard-1-131133944396956249 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Dashboard 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\ 
    Machine name: W104QWRX52 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 19332 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: Login failed for user 'sc'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.PrepareCommand(SqlCommand command, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, Boolean& mustCloseConnection)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText)
   at Helper.getProductCount() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\App_Code\helper.cs:line 44
   at charts_ProductCount.GenerateProductCountChart() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 24
   at charts_ProductCount.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 18
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/Dashboard/Home.aspx 
    Request path: /Dashboard/Home.aspx 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 14 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.PrepareCommand(SqlCommand command, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, Boolean& mustCloseConnection)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText)
   at Helper.getProductCount() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\App_Code\helper.cs:line 44
   at charts_ProductCount.GenerateProductCountChart() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 24
   at charts_ProductCount.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 18
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

I've been through several posts suggesting to create user/assign permission/change connection string etc but none has helped so far. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you successfully connect to the database you are trying to connect the application to using Management Studio using the "sc" user? Is there a default database for the "sc" user?  Is the default database the same database you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes. Yes and Yes. If I use the same code before deploying on IIS. it works just fine but when put on IIS it gives login error.

Comment: Try changing the value for "initial catalog" to the database you are trying to connect to, Example, ;Initial Catalog=test;

Comment: I can connect to same DB via Windows Authentication when on local system (but not when on IIS, both sql and windows authentication don't work)